# iPhone dev on mac Mini

Tags: iphone, macos

I plan to start iPhone Dev. Is a Mac mini 2.26 GHz with 2Go memory powerful enough?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568604/mac-mini-for-iphone-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have mac mini with such processor and only 1GB memory. This is not bad for developing. With 2Gb it will be OK too.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly powerful enough. A 7200rpm drive is a cheap improvement, a SSD much more expensive but also more dramatic improvement. Your mini may not be capable of accepting 4GB RAM depending on generation but if it is, it's a cheap sweetener.

Answer (score 0):

I do regular OS X development on a two year old Macbook, which is more than sufficient. Although I would recommend putting in more RAM. I bought 2x2GB for ~150 USD, which really made a difference. Just make sure that it's actually somewhat easy to replace your RAM, IIRC it's quite difficult on some Mini's.

Update: There are some good picture guides on [iFixIt](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Browse/Mac_mini) - and if we look at one for the A1283 it seems [pretty difficult, put possible](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Mac-mini-Model-A1283-RAM/1058/1).

Comment: You seem to be correct. That's a shame, considering it is done in 3 minutes on the Macbooks. Anyways, updated answer with links to some guides.

Answer (score -1):

Xcode 10 or newer:

MAC mini 2018 is suitable for iOS programming.

Mac mini 2014 late: Use SSD for batter performance(also use for iOS programming)

Use SSD
Min 8 GB Ram(Batter Experience then 4 GB)